# How to check which PHP extensions have been enabled/disabled in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04, php-extension

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS on my local machine. I've installed LAMP long ago on my machine. Now I want to enable following PHP extensions:

1. php_zip
2. php_xml
3. php_gd2

For it first I want to check whether these PHP extensions are enabled or not. I searched a lot about how to check the installed/enabled PHP extensions but every time I found how to install these extensions on Ubuntu Linux. So can someone please let me know how should I check the enabled/disabled PHP extensions in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS?

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Pop that into a php file and run it.

Comment: Have you looked at the output from phpinfo()?

Comment: Try this in terminal `php -m` you will see the available modules.

Comment: @RahilWazir:I tried php -m in terminal and some modules listed there. So does that mean these modules are enabled on my machine?

Comment: @PHPLover - they're enabled for executing PHP via the CLI, but not necessarily for the web SAPI as they can each have different ini files, with different modules enabled/disabled

Answer (score 199, accepted):

### Checking for installed php modules and packages

In addition to running

```
php -m
```

to get the list of installed php **modules**, you will probably find it helpful to get the list of the currently installed php **packages** in Ubuntu:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep php
```

This is helpful since Ubuntu makes php **modules** available via **packages**.

You can then install the needed **modules** by selecting from the available Ubuntu php **packages**, which you can view by running:

```
sudo apt-cache search php | grep "^php5-"
```

Or, for Ubuntu 16.04 and higher:

```
sudo apt-cache search php | grep "^php7"
```

As you have mentioned, there is plenty of information available on the actual installation of the packages that you might require, so I won't go into detail about that here.

### Related: Enabling / disabling installed php modules

It is possible that an **installed module** has been **disabled**. In that case, it won't show up when running `php -m`, but it will show up in the list of installed Ubuntu packages.

Modules can be enabled/disabled via the `php5enmod` tool (`phpenmod` on later distros) which is part of the `php-common` package.

**Ubuntu 12.04:**

Enabled modules are symlinked in `/etc/php5/conf.d`

**Ubuntu 12.04: (with PHP 5.4+)**

To *enable* an installed module:

```
php5enmod <modulename>
```

To *disable* an installed module:

```
php5dismod <modulename>
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 (php7) and higher:**

To *enable* an installed module:

```
phpenmod <modulename>
```

To *disable* an installed module:

```
phpdismod <modulename>
```

**Reload Apache**

Remember to reload Apache2 after enabling/disabling:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Check the answer from @tahsin-abrar too if you would like to check whether the extension is enable from the script.

Comment: Many modules set themselves to be loaded on Apache start when they are installed. They will still show up when you run `php -m` but it will not be enabled until you restart Apache. So you should run, on Debian/Ubuntu for example: `apt install -y php-gd php-curl && systemctl restart apache2.service`

Answer (score 41):

To check if this extensions are enabled or not, you can create a php file i.e. `info.php` and write the following code there:

```
<?php 
echo "GD: ", extension_loaded('gd') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
echo "XML: ", extension_loaded('xml') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
echo "zip: ", extension_loaded('zip') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
?>
```

That's it.

Comment: so this gives if extension is enabled or not.. how to find if it is installed or not using php??

Comment: Umm.. I think you need to check `phpinfo()` for getting the information. If you don't find the extension details in the `phpinfo()`, then it means it is not installed. I don't find any other way around.

Answer (score 9):

You can view which modules (compiled in) are available via terminal through `php -m`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the easiest way to see which extensions are (compiled and) loaded (not in cli) is to have a server run the following:

```
<?php
$ext = get_loaded_extensions();
asort($ext);
foreach ($ext as $ref) {
    echo $ref . "\n";
}
```

PHP cli does not necessarily have the same extensions loaded.

Comment: +1 for recognizing there are reasons someone might want to programmatically check a list of enabled extensions.

Answer (score 4):

For information on `php extensions` etc, on site.

1. Create a new file and name it `info.php` (or some other `name.php`)
2. Write this code in it:

   ```
    <?php
      phpinfo ();
    ?>
   ```
3. Save the file in the `root` (home)of the site
4. Open the file in your browser. For example: `example.com/info.php`
   All the `php` information on your site will be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Search extension in

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to see if a module is enabled / disabled vs only installed or not is to use **phpquery** command.

For example, on my Linux Mint machine, if I want to see if xdebug is enabled I would run:

```bash
 phpquery -v 8.1 -s apache2 -m xdebug
```

-v - is to specify for which version you want

-s - to specify the environment (apache2 or cli)

-m - the module you are interested into.

The response for the above example was (in my case):

```bash
xdebug (Enabled for apache2 by maintainer script)
```

[Here](https://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/phpquery) some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on PHP 8.1:

#### Check extension INSTALLED (in Operative System):

```
php -m
```

#### Check extension LOADED (in CLI):

```
# set EXT value with the desired extension name.
EXT=gmp php -r "echo getenv('EXT'),': ', extension_loaded( getenv('EXT') ) ? 'Loaded' : 'Not loaded', PHP_EOL;"
```

#### Check extension LOADED (in PHP-FPM):

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > public/info.php
```

and then visit `you-running-php-fpm-host/info.php`; remember to **delete the file afterwards!**