# How to check extensions are enabled in PHP.ini via PHP CODE

Tags: php, php-extension

I want to check the `geo_ip` extension in **php.ini** via PHP CODE

But i dont know, how to check ?

Is any solutions are available to check the extensions are enabled or not in **php.ini**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12

Comment: `php -m` through terminal.

Comment: You can get complete answer from already answered. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12).

Comment: I wanna to check via PHP CODE.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the extension_loaded function of SPL

```
$sExtensionName = 'geoip';
if (!extension_loaded($sExtensionName)) {
    exit("Error extension {$sExtensionName} not loaded");
}
```

Reference [function.extension-loaded.php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.extension-loaded.php)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by via PHP CODE.

If you are trying to check enabled PHP extension in your web server without using Terminal/SSH or any commands, then you can try the described way to check using your browser.

Create a PHP file(file with .php extension). for example, `checkEnabledExtension.php`

Now edit the file and add the following codes and save it:

```
<?php

$extensionName = "mysqli"; // replace mysqli by the extension name your want to check. for example: $extensionName = "geoip"; I am not sure about the name of the geo_ip extension.
echo $extensionName;
if(extension_loaded($extensionName)) {  // check extension_loaded() in PHP manual for details
    echo ": is Enabled."; // if the extension is enabled this block will run
} else {
    echo ": is NOT Enabled."; // this block will run if the extension is not enabled
}

?>
```

Now upload the file to your web root directory. For example: if your domain name is example.com then upload it to web root/public_html of the example.com

Now in your browser go to `domain.com/checkEnabledExtension.php`

That is it. You will see if the extension is enabled or not.

**To check a list of all enabled extension:**

use this PHP codes in `checkEnabledExtension.php` file to get the list of all enabled php extensions instead of checking a single. Use the same procedures above just use these codes:

```
<?php

print "<pre>"; print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); print "</pre>"; // this will print a list of all enabled PHP extension 

?>
```

BEST OF LUCK