# Installing Lapack on PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, lapack

I am trying to install Lapack to use it with PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.lapack.php) as it is the only PHP library that I have found that contains computations for singular values.

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 server with Apache2.

I have installed gfortran and liblapack-dev as instructed on other websites, but they all stop short of describing how to include it. In short, I get an qerror when calling a static function from Lapack, saying that it is not a defined class.

I figure that my next step is enabling the extension, but despite following this question ([How to check which PHP extensions have been enabled/disabled in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12)) I found no mention of Lapack. How should I resume to install Lapack for PHP? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you find someone who has created a binary package for your Ubuntu version, I'm afraid you'll have to install the C development packages and compile the extension yourself as instructed in the PHP manual. (I strongly suggest you look for a binary package first.)

Comment: Did you check that you were in the right php config file? (Sometimes, the CGI and the CLI don't use the same php.ini). You can check the phpinfo(); function both in your console and in your browser to make sure the extension is enabled in both environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Installing Lapack from source**

*Note: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.*

Install prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev git svn cmake gfortran liblapack-dev
```

Follow the instructions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/lapack.installation.php) (copied for convenience):

```
svn co https://icl.cs.utk.edu/svn/lapack-dev/lapack/trunk lapack
cd lapack
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D LAPACKE=ON ../
make 
sudo make install
```

This will create the Lapack shared library.
Now clone the php extension from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/ianbarber/php-lapack
```

And follow [the instructions as described there](https://github.com/ianbarber/php-lapack):

```
cd php-lapack
phpize
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Check if the extension is installed: `php -m | grep -i lapack`

Note that the extension is most likely incompatible with PHP 7, as it has not been updated for over 5 years.

Comment: This is what I meant with *install the C development packages and compile the extension yourself*. And a pretty good explanation, if you want my opinion.